# Find diagonalizing matrix when transformations of submatrices are already known.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, hermitian-matrices

I have currently a problem with a 8x8 matrix and maybe someone knows a neat trick how to solve this in an elegant way.

I have an 8x8 matrix consisting of four  4x4 submatrices:

$M=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
B^{\dagger} & -\tilde{A} 
\end{pmatrix}$

So $A$ and $-\tilde{A}$ have the same structure with different values. All submatrices are hermitian and thus $M$ is also hermitian.

Now: I already know the analytic results for the diagonalization of each submatrix, i.e. I already have all $U_X$ for which I get the diagonal matrix $D_X$:

$ D_X = U_X^{\dagger} X U_X$  for $X=A,B,\tilde{A}$.

So the question: outgoing from the 4 transformations which diagonalize the submatrices, is there a smart way to construct the transformation which diagonalizes $M$?

Edit: yes, $A$,$B$ and $\tilde{A}$ are hermitian
Edit2: Notation changed for clarity

Comment: When you say that all submatrices are Hermitian, does this mean that $B$ is also Hermitian?

Comment: I doubt it. Think about how $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ works out...

Comment: For clarification: all of the 4 submatrices are hermitian.

Comment: @Djoser42 Okay, it wasn't clear to me because you had written $B^*$, which is strange if $B$ is Hermitian.

Comment: Bit confused about my notation too ... Guess it should be a dagger. I will review my notes. Meanwhile I edited the matrix

Comment: @Djoser If you're only looking for the *signs* of the eigenvalues, then you might be able to save some effort by using the Schur complement